# Check whether a div has a child with a certain attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes

I'm trying to find the syntax to determine whether a div has a child div containing the `data-role` attribute set to `header`. I've tried these things with no luck:

```
$('div[data-role*="page"]').each(function(i) {
    if($(this).children('div').attr('data-role')=='header';) {
        alert("has header");
    }
});
```

```
$('div[data-role*="page"]').each(function(i) {
    if($(this).children('div[data-role*="header"]').length!=0;) {
        alert("has header");
    }
});
```

Comment: As mentioned elsewhere, in the answers, the semi-colons `;` are not required inside of the `if` statements/checks. It's sometimes worth checking with [JS Lint](http://jslint.com/) in the event that something doesn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In this example you have a trailing `;` after `!=0;`

```
$('div[data-role*="page"]').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).children('div[data-role="header"]').length != 0) {
        alert("has header");
    }
});
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/CMDEU/1/).

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
if ($('div[data-role*="page"]').has("div[data-role=header]").size() > 0)
    alert("Has header");
```

**Reference:** http://api.jquery.com/has/

Answer (score 5):

If I'm reading this correctly then the following should work:

```
$('div[data-role=page]:has(div[data-role])').css('border','1px solid #ccc');
```

to select any div that contains a child div with the attribute of 'data-role'.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qPcDv/1).

While you seem to want to utilise an `if` to trigger an `alert()`, this *seems* unnecessary since the above will function as a selector. If no elements are matched by that selector then, in the use-case I demonstrate, no elements will be affected. On the other hand, if an element is, or multiple elements are, selected then those will be.

Comment: You can also use it like: `var myDiv = $('div[data-role=page]'); myDiv.has('div[data-role])').css('border','1px solid #ccc');`

Answer (score 4):

This will select those divs that are child elements (with data-role attributes set to header) that are children of a div.

```
$('div > div[data-role=header]')
```